# Count consecutive digits in binary string

Tags: python, recursion, binary, compression

For a homework problem, we are asked to define a function that will count the number of consecutive digits in a binary string, and return the number.

For example, the function should return `n = [4,8,4,3,15]` for the binary input `S = ‘1111000000001111000111111111111111’`.

I have this so far, but I know it's not correct, and I do not know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated!

```
def consecutive_length(s):
    if s == '':
        return 0
    if s[0] == 0:
        return 0
    return 1 + consecutive_length(s[1:])
```

***Note:*** *we cannot use any loops. It is required that we do this with recursion.*

Thank you!

Comment: What about writing a simple loop that iterate over the string, keeps track of the last found digit, increments a counter whenever the next character is identical to the one being tracked. When the character changes, add the counter to a list and reinitializes the counter.

Comment: @innoSPG That was my initial thought, but we are not allowed to use any loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hopefully pythonic way (ignoring the fact that it's not pythonic to solve this kind of problem recursively):

```
def consecutive_length(s):
    def sub(idx, lst, last_char, count):
        try:
            c = s[idx]     # c will be the 'next' char
        except IndexError: # no more chars left to process
            if count:
                lst.append(count)
            return lst
        if c != last_char:
            lst.append(count)
            count = 0
        return sub(idx+1, lst, c, count+1)                            
    return sub(0, [], s[0] if s else None, 0)
```

where

- the outer function just takes the string as an argument and hides the inner functions additional parameters
- `idx` is the index to the string, we don't allocate a new string at every recursive call (and s[idx] is O(1) iirc)
- instead of computing the length of the string, we wait for an exception to happen (EAFP - Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission)

Testing:

```
>>> print consecutive_length('1111000000001111000111111111111111')
[4, 8, 4, 3, 15]    
>>> print consecutive_length('1111000000001111000111111111111110')
[4, 8, 4, 3, 14, 1]
>>> print consecutive_length('1')
[1]
>>> print consecutive_length('0')
[1]
>>> print consecutive_length('')
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here the '11' is a consecutive sequence of 1's .So '111' has 2 consecutive one's.  This solution is, if loops is not a problem. Use index to find '11' and keep doing it until you find no more. The below program shows the number of consecutive 1's .

```
cnt = 0
pos = -1
while True:
    try:
        pos = '111001100101111'.index('11', pos+1)
        cnt += 1
    except ValueError:
        print cnt
        break
```

**Result:**

```
6
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: uselpa has a much better way of doing it.

Since loops aren't allowed:

```
def consecutive_length(s, output, prev_char, count):
    # if end of string, append last count and return output
    if s == '':
        output.append(count)
        return output
    # if curr_char is same as prev_char, add 1 to count and parse next char
    if s[0] == prev_char:
        return consecutive_length(s[1:], output, s[0], count + 1)
    # if curr_char is diff from prev_char, append count and reset count to 1
    else:
        prev_char = s[0]
        output.append(count)
        return consecutive_length(s[1:], output, s[0], 1)
```

Call it with `consecutive_length(s, [], s[0], 0)`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without any additional inputs, using only the string as an input?

Comment: Posting solution for homework is not helping the student. The best approach is to give guidance for the OP to solve the problem while understanding what he is doing. Otherwise we end up with graduates who are not able to reason by themselves.

Comment: Oh. Sorry about that, innoSPG. I thought that adding the comments would help by explaining the logic behind it. Although in the end, I still eliminated the reasoning step of the homework.

Comment: @ChuckLoganLim  What should the additional parameters be set to when calling your function?

Comment: @uselpa, Sorry, forgot to add that. Let me edit the answer to provide defaults.

Comment: @innoSPG, I'm afraid I don't know how one would go about recursively generating a list of values that themselves will generate recursively. Is there perhaps any method you know of? My naive guess is to have two functions for this: one to get the count of consecutive chars in a substring, another to append the count returned by the earlier function into a list. Perhaps this will help, @jape?

Comment: @ChuckLoganLim Your function doesn't work if called twice in the same program because of `output=[]`. Also, the last `else` is not necessary.

Comment: @uselpa, Ah, you're right. I called it with `consecutive_length(s, [], s[0], 0)` when testing it out. I carelessly switched it over to use those defaults, instead.

How is the last `else` unnecessary? Do you mean that it can be eliminated because the `if` clause already returns, so there is no need for it?

Comment: Just the `else:` line, not the code after that, since there's a `return` right before that. Same as you did at the beginning of your function.

Comment: @uselpa, yes, that is what I meant. My wording was ambiguous.

Comment: You're right. I'll just refer to your answer instead :))